# shell_exec() не может запустить kdeconnect-cli

Tags: php, linux, bash, shell, sms

Хочу автоматизировать отправку смс с помощью kdeconnect-cli. При создании PHP сценария пробовал использовать exec(), но функция ничего не возвращает и не выполняет. Команды в терминале работают: `kdeconnect-cli --send-sms 'Ваш код подтверждения: 8909' --destination '8929...`. Пробовал другие команды вызывать через exec() или shell_exec(), но они работают правильно( к примеру, git). Хотя и у git и kdeconnect-cli одинаковые владельцы и права доступа:

> -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 75K Mar  1  2023 /usr/bin/kdeconnect-cli

В чем может быть проблема?

UPD:
Пробовал запускать и через crontab: все тщетно(видимо, проблема в самом kdeconnect-cli). Искал в англоязычных ресурсах. Решения так никто и не предложил.

Comment: Попробуйте указать абсолютный путь до приложения, возможно в PHP переменная PATH не содержит нужной директории

Comment: Пробовал, к сожалению, не помогло.